# How can I log resolver/operation name and duration in HotChocolate?

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate

I'm trying to log some basic gql method details - resolver/operation name and duration. `I've started looking at using .AddHttpRequestInterceptor((context, executor, builder, ct)`
and getting the info from the builder, but even though I can see it in the debugger, the method name is buried in private members like:
`((HotChocolate.Execution.QueryRequestBuilder)builder)._query.Document.Definitions[0].SelectionSet.Selections[0].Name.Value`

I'm sure there's an easier and better way to hook into the pipeline to get the method name and log it with the call duration.

I found an article written about GraphQL.Net that uses DefaultGraphQLExecuter  -
`public class GraphQLExecutorWithDiagnostics<TSchema> : DefaultGraphQLExecuter<TSchema>`
which provides an operationName parameter within the
`Task<ExecutionResult> ExecuteAsync(`
, which looks ideal.

I'll be logging to AppInsights, but that's not relevant for now, I just want to get the info first.
I'm using v11.0.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `DiagnosticEventListener`

You can just extend this base class and override the methods that you need for you logging.

```cs
public class CustomDiagnosticListener : DiagnosticEventListener
{
    public override IActivityScope ExecuteRequest(IRequestContext context)
    {
        return EmptyScope;
    }

    public virtual IActivityScope ResolveFieldValue(IMiddlewareContext context)
    {
        return EmptyScope;
    }
}
```

To use this diagnostic listener you have to add it to the schema

```cs
services.AddGraphQLServer()
    ...
   .AddDiagnosticEventListener<CustomDiagnosticListener>()
```

In case you have dependencies that you listener has to reslove you have to reslove them manually:

```cs
services.AddGraphQLServer()
    ...
   .AddDiagnosticEventListener<CustomDiagnosticListener>(
         sp => new CustomDiagnosticListener(
                sp.GetApplicationService<MyDependency>()))
```

Comment: This helped me to add an error filter in my pipeline, i did not know how to include a dependency for a logger in the case of an erro, and the last block of code, did the job. 

Thanks man.